# Cell Editing on ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to make my grid.Panel cells editable with one click. I have following code that doesn't work. I followed this [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2lo) link and implemented in my program but still clicking doesn't enable editing. I also tried RowEditing but it didn't work either. There is no problem getting info from database.

```js
Ext.define('CategoryNumberGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  selType: 'cellmodel',
  pageSize: 25,
  defineColumns:function(){
    this.columns=[
    {
      header: 'Code',
      dataIndex: 'code',
      renderer: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode
    },{
      header: 'Description',
      dataIndex: 'descr',
      renderer: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode
    }];
  },
  model: 'CategoryNumberModel',
  initComponent:function(){
    this.defineColumns();
    var config = {
      autoLoad: true,
      autoSync: true,
      remoteFilter: true,
      remoteSort: true,
      proxy: getProxy("CategoryNumberModel"),
      model: 'CategoryNumberModel',
      sorters:[
      {
        property:'code',
        direction:'ASC'
      }],
      pageSize: this.pageSize
    };
    this.Store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', config);
    this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
      clicksToEdit:1});
    this.plugins=[this.editing];
    this.callParent();
  }
});
```

Comment: What is this.editing in you case. grid don't have any editing config.

Comment: [I have put your code into a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f41) but I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getProxy is not defined`.

Comment: Have you tried to add editors to the columns? [Config `column.editor`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your sample is not complete (not runnable) as per the question guidelines.
- JavaScript is case-sensitive. `this.Store` won't help a grid to find its data.
- Your columns are lacking the [`editor` config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-editor).

I have corrected the issues: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f41

For future questions, please consider making a working fiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on a virtual machine and I'm not able to copy paste the code so wrote it here by hand and because of that I miss-typed "this.store". Thanks for editing, I'm pretty new to Extjs (working for just 1.5 week) and I didn't know that we could put code to fiddle. Thanks again it worked.